# A Haxe package for Goto Declaration?

Tags: haxe, atom-editor

Is there any one who can recommend an Atom package for haxe that would enable goto declaration of a property of a method in a class?

Comment: Do you have try [VSCode + Haxe Support plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nadako.vshaxe)? 

It supports goto declaration

Comment: Thanks, I will try and see,,

Comment: Or [HaxeDevelop](http://haxedevelop.org/) the most complete at this time, but only support on Windows

Comment: I am want to develop on Mac without crossover, or VM..

Comment: On Mac, VSCode + Haxe plugin is best solution at this time.

Comment: the sublime text package for haxe does have rudimentary goto definition, but I've only gotten it to work with haxe-flixel and openfl projects so far (i m sure it can work with others if configured properly). The kha IDE  [KodeStudio](https://github.com/KTXSoftware/KodeStudio) (based on visualstudio code + haxe plugin) also works quite nicely, but only works for kha projects so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Atom you can use for Haxe Toolkit the Haxe package, and the language-haxe package also, if you want to develop on Haxe for games you can use the Heaps Toolkit also, who is also developed from the same guys as Haxe. You can search for videos about this, they are several, also you can use Haxe with OpenFL so you can develop with Flash, but believe me, its not Flash.

One more thing in Atom, it is enough just to create a javascript project, from there you are safe.